Why \ref doesn't work with tcolorbox
I have found and modified this code:
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=2pt,itemsep=2pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.5in,bottom=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,footskip=0.3in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted} % tcolorbox minted library, required to use the "minted" tcb listing engine (this library is not loaded by the option [most])
\usepackage{minted} % Allows input of raw code, such as Python code
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % ALWAYS load this package LAST

% Custom tcolorbox style for Python code (not the code or the box it appears in, just the options for the box)
\tcbset{
    pythoncodebox/.style={
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable,
        colback=gray!10, colframe=gray!20!black,
        boxrule=1pt, top=2pt, bottom=2pt, left=2pt, right=2pt,
        sharp corners, before skip=10pt, after skip=10pt,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={
            empty,
            top=0pt, bottom=0pt, left=2pt, right=2pt,
            interior code={
                \fill[fill=tcbcolframe] (frame.south west)
                --([yshift=-4pt]frame.north west)
                to[out=90,in=180] ([xshift=4pt]frame.north west)
                --([xshift=-8pt]frame.north east)
                to[out=0,in=180] ([xshift=16pt]frame.south east)
                --cycle;
            }
        },
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
        listing only
    },
    pythoncodebox/.default={}, % Default is No title
    
}

% Creazione dei nuovi ambienti tcolorbox
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{pythonbox}[2][]{
    pythoncodebox, % Usa lo stile definito sopra
    title={#1}, % Assegna il titolo
    label={#2},
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=python,
    minted options={autogobble,breaklines,mathescape}
}
% Creazione degli ambienti Python personalizzati con label, caption e riferimenti
\NewTCBListing[auto counter, number within=section]{python}{ !O{} !D(){} !G{} }{
    pythoncodebox, % Usa lo stile base
    title={\textbf{\lstlistingname \thetcbcounter: #1}}, % Titolo sopra il codice
    label={code:\thetcbcounter: #2} % Label automatica
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=python,
    minted options={autogobble,breaklines,mathescape},
    before upper={%
        \refstepcounter{tcbcounter}
        \addcontentsline{lol}{section}{\thetcbcounter ~~~ #1}% Aggiunta alla lista dei codici
        }
}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Cell } % Caption name of code snippets
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Cells list}

\begin{document}

% Inserimento del sommario
\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Inserimento della lista delle figure
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\lstlistlistingname}
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage

\section{Question 1}\label{sec:question_1}
\subsection{Libraries and datasets loads}

\hspace{0.7em} First of all the libraries needed are installed using the Anaconda Powershell Prompt. They are imported in the Notebook as cell \ref{code:lib1} shows.

\begin{python}[Importing libraries]{code:lib1}
import os
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
import sklearn # pip install sklearn
from tqdm import tqdm
import joblib
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
import random
\end{python}

After that it is possible to load datasets (cell \ref{code:loadD}) on the Notebook using \textbf{.read\_csv()} method.

\begin{python}[Loading datatsets]{code:loadD}
# Load .csv files
df1 = pd.read_csv('dataset/dataset/mitbih_train.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('dataset/dataset/mitbih_test.csv')
\end{python}

Each \textit{".csv"} file is now loaded as a dataframe in the variables df1 and df2.
Thanks to that it is now possible to use other methods to analyze them.

See \textbf{Cell~\ref{code:lib1}} for library imports.

\end{document}

The \ref{} after compiling returns '??' but I cannot understand why and so how to fix it.

I don't have minted installed, so I can't compile your code, but the name of the counter in your \refstepcounter{tcbcounter} should be \tcbcounter. It needs the backslash because tcbcounter is not the actual name of the counter, the macro \tcbcounter is a pointer to the actual name.

The empty line in \tcbset{...} will cause an error.


As noted, your code produces errors.  You cannot worry about references until you fix your errors:
You can't have a blank line in tcbset.
The argument to \refstepcounter{tcbcounter} should be \tcbcounter with a slash.
But the references still don't work, because
The specification !O{} !D(){} !G{} means that argument 1 is delimited by [], argument 2 by (), and argument 3 by {}, with all three optional (and defaulting to blank).  This means that when you say \begin{python}[Importing libraries]{code:lib1}, you're passing the label to #3, not #2.  But #3 is never used.  Instead, use the argument specification O{} m.  (The G has even been removed from more recent LaTeXs, because optional {} is so un-LaTeX.)
label={code:\thetcbcounter: #2} means that  your label will end up with that form.  So you would have to use \ref{code:1.2: code:lib1}.  But using counters in labels defeats the entire point of labels.  So just use label={#2}.
Now things are working, but
The \refstepcounter steps the counter unnecessarily, so we can take it out.
Other notes:
Don't \hspace{0.7em}.  See No indent in the first paragraph in a section?
It's a bit strange that you're allowing the title to be optional, since without it your title ends up being "Cell 1.1: ".  If you want the title to be optional, then you should accomodate a missing title.  Otherwise, make the title required with a specification of mm.
You never use pythonbox, so I'm not sure why you have it.  I've deleted it.
Don't include the space in \lstlistingname.  Instead, make sure you have a space after its use if you need it by using ~ or \ .  The final product:

\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=2pt,itemsep=2pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.5in,bottom=0.2in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,footskip=0.3in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted} % tcolorbox minted library, required to use the "minted" tcb listing engine (this library is not loaded by the option [most])
\usepackage{minted} % Allows input of raw code, such as Python code
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % ALWAYS load this package LAST (but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/107497)


% Custom tcolorbox style for Python code (not the code or the box it appears in, just the options for the box)
\tcbset{
    pythoncodebox/.style={
        enhanced jigsaw, breakable,
        colback=gray!10, colframe=gray!20!black,
        boxrule=1pt, top=2pt, bottom=2pt, left=2pt, right=2pt,
        sharp corners, before skip=10pt, after skip=10pt,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={
            empty,
            top=0pt, bottom=0pt, left=2pt, right=2pt,
            interior code={
                \fill[fill=tcbcolframe] (frame.south west)
                --([yshift=-4pt]frame.north west)
                to[out=90,in=180] ([xshift=4pt]frame.north west)
                --([xshift=-8pt]frame.north east)
                to[out=0,in=180] ([xshift=16pt]frame.south east)
                --cycle;
            }
        },
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
        listing only
    },
    pythoncodebox/.default={}, % Default is No title
    % #1
}

% Creazione dei nuovi ambienti tcolorbox #8
% Creazione degli ambienti Python personalizzati con label, caption e riferimenti
\NewTCBListing[auto counter, number within=section]{python}{ O{} m }{% #3
    pythoncodebox, % Usa lo stile base
    title={\textbf{\lstlistingname\ \thetcbcounter: #1}}, % Titolo sopra il codice
    label={#2}, % Label automatica.  #4
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=python,
    minted options={autogobble,breaklines,mathescape},
    before upper={%
        %\refstepcounter{\tcbcounter} % #2, #5
        \addcontentsline{lol}{section}{\thetcbcounter ~~~ #1}% Aggiunta alla lista dei codici
        }
}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Cell} % #9
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Cells list}

\begin{document}

% Inserimento del sommario
\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Inserimento della lista delle figure
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\lstlistlistingname}
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage

\section{Question 1}\label{sec:question_1}
\subsection{Libraries and datasets loads}

%\hspace{0.7em} #6
First of all the libraries needed are installed using the Anaconda Powershell Prompt. They are imported in the Notebook as cell \ref{code:lib1} shows.

\begin{python}[Importing libraries]{code:lib1}
import os
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
import sklearn # pip install sklearn
from tqdm import tqdm
import joblib
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
import random
\end{python}

After that it is possible to load datasets (cell \ref{code:loadD}) on the Notebook using \textbf{.read\_csv()} method.

\begin{python}[Loading datatsets]{code:loadD}
# Load .csv files
df1 = pd.read_csv('dataset/dataset/mitbih_train.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('dataset/dataset/mitbih_test.csv')
\end{python}

Each \textit{".csv"} file is now loaded as a dataframe in the variables df1 and df2.
Thanks to that it is now possible to use other methods to analyze them.

See \textbf{Cell~\ref{code:lib1}} for library imports.

\end{document}



Thanks, now it works
